# How do I use a cell reference in a filter?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, contains

I have an excel macro that I want to filter for rows that do not contain some specific text. The following code displays all rows that do not contain the text "lac" in column C.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$100000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "<>*lac*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

However instead of filtering for "does not contain lac", I want it to filter for "does not contain the text in sheet 2, cell A3".

I have tried replacing "lac" with the cell reference or with a variable set to the cell value, and tried variations of removing quotes, substituting parenthesis, etc., but haven't stumbled upon the correct syntax.

What is the syntax for using a cell reference or a variable in place of "lac"?

Comment: `"<>*" & Sheet2.Range("A3").Value & "*"`

Comment: I inserted the above code but I'm getting a "Compile error: Expected: end of statement". Here is what I have.     
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$100000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*" & Sheet2.Range("A3").Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd

Comment: I figured it out. this works.         ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$100000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Value & "*", Operator:=xlAnd